# system hangs up during a build procedure in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, fastcgi

Myself trying to build a stack for my embedded system.While building opensource component fcgi, my system got stuck and reboots.The command it last trying to execute is given below.

```
/bin/sh ../libtool --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I..   -I../include -pthread -g -O2 -Wall -c -o libfcgi_la-fcgiapp.lo `test -f fcgiapp.c || echo './'`fcgiapp.c
```

The error i got from logs is

```
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Hangup
make[2]: *** [libfcgi_la-fcgiapp.lo] Hangup
make: *** [all] Hangup
```

How can I fix this??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

"Hangup" means that someone sent the SIGHUP signal to those processes.  Typically this happens when you log out; all the processes you left running are sent a SIGHUP to clean themselves up.  It also happens when a system reboots: all the processes on the system are sent a SIGHUP so they can stop cleanly and flush buffers to disk, etc.

So these messages are not *causing* your embedded system to reboot.  It seems much more likely they're a *result* of your system rebooting (or shutting down, anyway) for some other reason.  You'll have to find that reason to solve the problem.